# How do I replace any instance of "" with null in an array of JSON strings in typescript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of JSON that looks like this:

```
[
{"test":"a","test1":"1","test2":""},
{"test":"b","test1":"","test2":"hi"}
{"test":"","test1":"3","test2":""}
]
```

I want it to look like this if there are any JSON strings with "" values

```
[
{"test":"a","test1":"1","test2":null},
{"test":"b","test1":null,"test2":"hi"}
{"test":null,"test1":"3","test2":null}
]
```

Comment: That's not an array of JSON strings, it's an array of objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Loop through the array, then loop through all the properties in each object. Test if the value is an empty string, if so replace it with `null`.

```js
const data = [
  {"test":"a","test1":"1","test2":""},
  {"test":"b","test1":"","test2":"hi"},
  {"test":"","test1":"3","test2":""}
];

data.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key] === "") {
      obj[key] = null;
    }
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the array and then each key of the objects, checking for a blank string. Like this:

```js
let data = [
  {"test":"a","test1":"1","test2":""},
  {"test":"b","test1":"","test2":"hi"},
  {"test":"","test1":"3","test2":""}
]

for (let entry of data) {
  Object.entries(entry).map(obj => {
    if (obj[1] === "") entry[obj[0]] = null;
  });
}

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need one line of code

```
data= JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(data).replaceAll("\"\"","null").replaceAll("\"\"","\""));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is as simple as efficient

```js
let data = [
{"test":"a","test1":"1","test2":""},
{"test":"b","test1":"","test2":"hi"},
{"test":"","test1":"3","test2":""}
]

for(let objData of data)
  for(let propr in objData)
    if(objData[propr] === "")
      objData[propr] = null;
      
console.log(data)
```